# Mongodb: get particular column values from a mongo collections

Tags: java, mongodb

trying to find the particular column values from mongo db collections using java code

```
 Bson newValue = new Document("_id", true);
   List<Document> collections = collection.find(newValue).into(new ArrayList<Document>());
```

but it returs nothing.

When i tried with following command in mongo shell it returns the data as expected.

```
 db.weather.find({},{_id:true}).pretty().
```

I dont know how to set {} in java code below

```
  List<Document> collections = collection.find(newValue).into(new ArrayList<Document>());
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply projection  for particular column,

```
         Document query = new Document();

         Document projection = new Document();
         projection.append("_id", 1);

         collection.find(query).projection(projection);
```